# the type org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryByExampleExecutor cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

Good morning, I have a head the end of the week with an error in the project that I'm doing for the study of springboot + angular + jpa.

At the time of doing a service management class, I used it according to the tutorial of an extended class of class JpaRepository.

But a project error that I can not solve.

Follow the pom.xml and some images of the project, if anyone can help I thank you!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>marco.prova</groupId>
<artifactId>apiweb</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>apiweb</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
<relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
<version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

Project images in STS.

https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/1-png-6e078f12-f26b-4266-8030-520f0f0fe7d1

https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/2-png-2224373b-2cec-46dc-b986-e68876ef57db

https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/3-png-740ac73d-5bd4-4f45-9394-c2717d4a9423

https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/4-png-9202635e-5a30-4f58-a862-70d3e9034ec6

I'm waiting! Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Or You can try to delete org.springframework.data folder from C:\Users\User\.m2 folder and update Maven project

Comment: Thanks a ton, of all the answers for these kind of question -- this is the most strightforward and simple way to fix.

Answer (score 8):

> the type
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryByExampleExecutor
>   cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class
>   files

You need to download [Spring data commons jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons/2.0.5.RELEASE) and keep it in your classpath.

Or add the following dependency in your POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` starter instead:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```